# Updating database while app is running

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So, this is what my app is doing. I have a file on the internet with a list of locations. I'm loading that file and saving locations at database on my phone. Also, on every 24 hours I am dowloading that same file and checking if it has some updates. What I want to do is next: I want to put in that file current version of the file, and when I download it I check that version with the previous one and if they are different, I want to drop my current table, and load all locations again.

Currently, my app is doing following: I have a alarm which triggers the IntentService which then downloads the file and checks for each location if it is in the database, and if it is not, then it inserts it.

I want: IntentService first to check if the version of the file downloaded is different from the previous one, and if it is, drops the table, and inserts all locations from the file in new table.

I'm managing my database with ContentProvider and SQLiteOpenHelper.
I guess I should somehow trigger the onUpgrade method of the SQLiteOpenHelper, but I don't know how to exactly do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put into onUpgrade method all database operations (ALTER TABLE, DROP, etc...) necessaries to update the database and not forget increase the database version.

When you increase the database version then onUpgrade method is automatically called on application first start after the update.

EDIT:

You can use a static field to set the database version:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

and pass to the super constructor:

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

and increase the DATABASE_VERSION when you need update the database (call to onUpgrade).

Comment: Does that means that in the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper I should put a increased database version?

Comment: Yes, I recommended use a static field to set the database version. and pass as argument into the super constructor

Comment: But my problem is that I'm calling that constructor from onCreate method of the ContentProvider, and I think that onCreate is called at the moment when app starts. Where should I call that constructor from, in that case? I can put my code, if it is easier

Comment: You can normally call to database constructor from anywhere. The only code changes requires are the version increment and the onUpgrade method implementation. When you call the database constructor the first time then onUpgrade methods is called.

Comment: If I understood, that means that I can call database constructor from my IntentService, with a new version of the database. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but I recommended you create the DATABASE_VERSION field and 
use it without having to pass it as a parameter in your constructor. Example: public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

Comment: Well, I tried to make it work, but I couldn't do it. I think the problem is that I don't want DATABASE_VERSION to be final, because I don't want to change it manually from code each time I change file. What I want is that when I check for the new version of the file, and I see that it is a new version, then current database should be dropped, and new one created. I can post my code, if you are not understanding me